# how configuration git pages based on hexo at multi pc

Tags: git, github-pages, blogs, hexo

a few months ago month ago, I configue git pages based on Hexo At MacBook.

And I want to configure git pages at Windows.

I know  the following

1. After hexo deploy command execute, I confirmed that the doucment i wrote was uploaded to gitpages.
2. unfotunely, hexo theme is not uploaded git pages. and i know that this sistuation.
3. so I created one more repository.
   The new repository is all items includeing wroted document, theme etc..
4. Now I tryed that i create ~/git/Blog/temp directory on windows PC.
   I went to ~/git/Blog/temp and entered the hexo init command.
5. i confirmed that is created file that related 'hexo init command'
6. In order to run the files that I originally managed locally
   After deleting the contents of the temp directory, I moved the contents of the new storage (the storage that manages documents and themes).

And when I entered the hexo server command, the server was running well.

7. But when I actually connect to localhost:4000, I get the following error:

No layout: index.html

Even when hexo init was done, there was no index.html file,

Among the previously uploaded repositories, it exists only in the repository that manages the entire source, not in the repository that only stores documents.

Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `hexo init` is not necessary for an existing source. Just copying all the previous files to the new place is enough. After the copying, you can use `hexo g` to generate pages in a folder called `public` or use `hexo s` to view it at localhost, and then you can use `hexo d` to deploy your pages.